# SQL QUERY using LEFT JOIN and CASE Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

**here is an example of my two table.**

[image]

**PROBLEM:**
How can I create SQL Query using left join?

**HERE IS THE SCENARIO**

As I've said earlier, I have two table (TABLE1 and TABLE2),
I tried to use left join so that i can combine both UserID
in one table

**so here is the code**

```
select * from table1 a left join table2 on a.userid = b.userid
```

so two tables are now combined.

**what i need to do is this:** 
if the status is **all complete** then 'complete' 
then if status contains **complete and incomplete** then 'incomplete' 
else 'no status'

it should be look like this.

[image]

**NOTE**: 
since **UserID = 1** (table1) contains **complete and incomplete** status (table2) 
then it display **'incomplete'** (new column) 

since **UserID = 4** (table1) contains **all complete** status (table 2) 
then it display **'completed'** (new column)

### -----------------------------------

**WHAT IF I CHANGE THE STATUS TO INTEGER?**

[image]

same procedure. thanks

Comment: Sigh. Why would you want this? You should be doing this on the application level.

Comment: that depends on so many things, I think this is quite valid

Comment: Your second illustration seems wrong.  Shouldn't line 7 read "incomplete?"

Comment: it should be complete because as you can see on table two. userid =4 contains 'complete' status

Comment: is it possible on sql query? i really don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.*, 
        CASE WHEN b.totalCount = 1 AND b.totalINC = 0 THEN 'Complete'
             WHEN totalCount IS NULL THEN ''
             ELSE 'Incomplete'
        END STatus
FROM    table1 a
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT  UserID, 
                    COUNT(DISTINCT STATUS) totalCount,
                    SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'Incomplete' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) totalINC
            FROM table2
            GROUP BY UserID
        ) b ON a.UserID = b.UserID
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d6ee1/4)

**UPDATE 1**

the only thing you'll change is the `CASE`

```
SELECT  a.*, 
        CASE WHEN b.totalCount = 1 AND b.totalINC = 0 THEN 'Complete'
             WHEN totalCount IS NULL THEN ''
             ELSE 'Incomplete'
        END STatus
FROM    table1 a
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT  UserID, 
                    COUNT(DISTINCT STATUS) totalCount,
                    SUM(CASE WHEN status <> 100 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) totalINC
            FROM table2
            GROUP BY UserID
        ) b ON a.UserID = b.UserID;
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/082a7/1)

Comment: that's what I'm looking for. But what if the status change to integer? **see updated question**

Comment: the only thing you'll change on the query is the `CASE` statement, `SUM(CASE WHEN status = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) totalINC` if 2 is for incomplete.

Comment: it counts the distinct number of your status, it returns 1 if you have only 1 type of status other wise 2 or more if you have other types. it will also return null if there is no existing values for the userID

Answer (score 5):

Easy, but tricky solution :

as INCOMPLETE is greater (for a db) than COMPLETE, you can simply do

```
SELECT a.UserID, 
  LOWER(COALESCE(MAX(b.status) , 'NO STATUS'))
  FROM table1 a 
 LEFT JOIN table2 b on a.userid = b.userid
 GROUP BY a.UserID
```

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0545d/8) (with Andomar's better solution as well)

Comment: +1 for the trickery, though would cause a pretty tough bug if the status was translated

Comment: @Andomar totally agree, and +1 to your "correct but harrassing" solution ;)

Comment: @gean08 you can google for : it's an ANSI SQL function which does: if the first parameter's value is null than take second's one (and so on if second is null take third's, etc.). In this case, MAX(NULL) = null, so if you have nothing in table2 for user of table a, it will return 'NO STATUS'

Answer (score 3):

```
select  a.UserID
,       case
        when sum(case when b.status = 'Incomplete' then 1 end) > 0 
            then 'Incomplete' 
        when sum(case when b.status = 'Complete' then 1 end) > 0 
            then 'Complete' 
        else 'No Status' 
        end
from    table1 a 
left join 
        table2 b
on      a.userid = b.userid
group by
        a.UserID
```